# Maven disable read from externalized application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I need to read a few maven properties in my Spring Boot code

I have created application.properties in my src/resources with the following content

```
usehttps=@usehttps@
verifycertificate=@verifycertificate@
```

My pom.xml has the following properties

```
<properties>
    <usehttps>true</usehttps>
    <verifycertificate>true</verifycertificate>
</properties>
```

And I use maven filtering to read from application.properties

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <finalName>http_lib</finalName>
</build>
```

I compile my code with command

```
mvn clean package -Dusehttps=false -Dverifycertificate=false
```

So from my code I can get the value passed during maven packaging

The problem is that if I create an application.properties file in the location where I run my jar, my code gets the value from the external application.properties. This might be a security issue, I need to force the application to get the value passed during packaging. Is there any way to achieve this?

Or, is there any way to pass parameters from maven to spring boot without using properties file?

Comment: Your question is all about https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html .

Comment: Is there any alternative using maven to pass parameters to spring boot without using resource files?

Comment: Maven is all about buildtime, whereas spring-boot is all about runtime. What you can do is to use Maven to start the application using https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/#goals-run in which case you can benefit from Maven features to run a springboot application.