# Spring boot force PropertySource to read from internal jar

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have my class that reads properties from application.properties in Spring Boot

```
@Configuration
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class TestUtil {


    @Value("${usehttps}")
    private String usehttps="";

    @Value("${verifycertificate}")
    private String verifycertificate="";

}
```

The problem is that I want my code to read the application.properties from my internal jar file only. application.properties is in src/main/resources. If I create an application.properties with same properties on the location where my jar resides, the properties get overwritten by the external file at runtime. It can be a security issue in my case.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Please explain your "security issue". You seem to be fighting core Boot functionality, which is unlikely to end well.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-In fact am using maven properties which I inject in my application.properties during packaging. These maven properties are sensitive boolean, they determine whether to enable encryption(production) or disable (development). Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62677131/maven-disable-read-from-externalized-application-properties for more information

Comment: Don't use maven profiles for this (it means you are deploying different artifacts to different environments and kind of deploy an untested version of your artifact!). Just specify the properties at runtime OR specify a Spring profile at startup to enable/disable encryption. You are basically working around Spring Boot core functionality.

Comment: It's also entirely pointless as it's very easy to modify a text file inside a jar.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Is there any alternative using maven to pass parameters to spring boot without using resource files?

Answer (score 0):

The order in which your jar file and properties file are found in `CLASSPATH` matters here, as well as classloaders hierarchy (which JarLauncher gives you).

You can try to redefine bean for [ResourcePatternResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/ResourcePatternResolver.html) in order to change this behavior and manually scan all classloaders for the resource.
But I would try a simple rearranging of CLASSPATH entries first.

Comment: This isn't the case with Boot, which has a custom classloader.

Answer (score 0):

This may quite late to answer it, but as I faced the same problem, I found the solution recommended by spring [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4#importing-additional-configuration).

However the solutions says to include internal config files into existing application.yml like

```
spring:
  config:
    import:
      - classpath:module1.yml #no space
      - classpath:module2.yml
```